# I want to display file list using file type

Tags: php, file-type

```
<?php
        //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
       $scan = scandir('uploads');

            foreach($scan as $file)
            {
               if (is_image("uploads/$file"))
                { ?>
                    <p><?php echo "this is an image"; ?></p>
            <?php        
                }
              if (is_pdf("uploads/$file"))
                { ?>
                    <p><?php echo "this is an PDF file"; ?></p>
            <?php        
                }
              if (is_html("uploads/$file"))
                { ?>
                    <p><?php echo "this is an HTML file"; ?></p>
            <?php        
                }


            }
       ?>
```

I want to display the file as file type. If the file is an image show this is an image, if the file is PDF show the file is PDF
Please Help me with this code. Pls, Pls

Comment: read more about [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: use this: `$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do a simple `str_pos()` / `substr()` to detect if the string contains a .pdf file extension or a .html or a .png/.jpg.

Here's some example code:

```
if (substr($filename, -4) == '.jpg') {
       echo "Jpeg!";
}
```

Just make the other switches for the different file types and you're golden. Ideally, pass all the files to one function and have all the logic contained there.

Comment: you can also get the extension using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Can you tell me why use -4 ?

Comment: yeah, as you can read at `http://php.net/substr` -- when you specify the a negative number, the function will start at the end and will read backwards, instead of starting at the front and reading forwards. The number of characters it reads is the absolute value of the parameter.

Comment: So `.html` is 5 chars from the end.  With all respect, this is probably the worst of solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**`DirectoryIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and its methods like this:

```
$scan = "uploads";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($scan);
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if (!$file->isDot()) {
        $ext = $file->getExtension();
        switch ($ext) {
            case "img":
            case "png":
            case "gif":
                $text = "This is an image";
                break;
            case "html":
                $text = "This is HTML";
                break;
            case "pdf":
                $text = "This is PDF";
                break;
            default:
                $text = "";
        }
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to rely on the file extension:

```
$fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

foreach(scandir('uploads') as $file) {
    echo finfo_file($fi, $file);
}
```

Or to get the extension:

```
echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```